# Delphi 7 and Excel 2007 Open File Error

Tags: delphi, excel-2007, ole

I am having difficulty opening a EXCEL 2007 in Delphi 7 It works for Office 2003 and below but the wonderful people at microsoft have sent an update or something and the delphi app fell over just earlier this month.

```
  oE := GetActiveOleObject('Excel.Application');
  oE.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFilename, UpdateLinks:=false, ReadOnly:=true); //Error
```

I get the following error:

> 'c:\Temp\Book1.xls' could not be
>   found. Check the spelling of the file
>   name, and verify that the file
>   location is correct.'#$A#$A'If you are
>   trying to open the file from your list
>   of most recently used files, make sure
>   that the file has not been renamed,
>   moved, or deleted'

Yet if I run the same command in VBA there is no problem.

Comment: What is the VBA script that you use to open the file?

Comment: In Excel Macro:
Application.Workbooks.Open "C:\Temp\Book1.xls", false,true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this sounds stupid, but have you manually confirmed that the file exists at that location?

What exactly is the contents of sFileName, is it the full path or only the filename? When it is only the filename, maybe Excel can't find it because its current working directory is something else. If you are only passing the filename, try the full path instead.

Comment: Yes, I copied the value into the equivilent VBA function and the file opened as expected full path and filename

Comment: @Traci: What happens when you put Books1.xls in C:\ and you change your call to `oE.Workbooks.Open(Filename:='c:\Books1.xls', UpdateLinks:=false, ReadOnly:=true);`?

Comment: Somehow the filename got a space prepended to it, I trimmed it and all OK

Answer (score 1):

the full code for the lookers :

```
uses ComObj; ..

procdure startExcel; 
var   
  oE:Variant; 
begin
  try 
    oE := GetActiveOleObject('Excel.Application');
  except
    oE := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application'); 
  end; 
  oE.Workbooks.Open(filename, false, false);
  oE.Visible := True; 
end;
```

[source](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoExcl.htm)